# Flex, How to create new custom label with combobox properties?

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, custom-component

i would like to create a new custom Label with Combobox properties.

A new custom component should like to be facebook's settings button pop up or similar
[image]

Comment: Did you have a question?  What properties do you want on your new custom label?  How do you expect it to work?  What have you tried?  Why didn't it work?

Comment: i would like show a dropdown when mouse over to the label

Answer (score 0):

If displaying label is a problem then you can use labelFunction.

Or if you want to show a menu then you can use menu component. It is available in flex.